# Is it possble to write query at JPA entity property level

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-annotations, persistence.xml

Is it possble to write query at JPA entity property level?

Basically I want to add a property in an entity which is not an actual column and value should computed with query.

Something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "quote", name = "QUOTE_SCENARIO")
public class QuoteScenario {
@Query(Select max(Lead_Time) from differentEntity)
private Integer leadTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible as the query annotation is at the method level. You can try and do this using [formula](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_derived_properties_performance_and) in Hibernate.